# Static Data Architecture for D3 visualization Best Practice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, d3.js

I currently have a running D3 data visualization that uses data from a JSON file with 500 objects to build a force layout graph.  The application is built using node and express.  Is it best practice to keep the data on the server side, even if it is a relatively small amount?  If moved to the server side, should it be stored in a mongo db, or just as JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a static visualization, I would say a JSON file would be just fine since it integrates easily with d3.js. If it is data that changes dynamically, a database could be a better choice since it could be easier to update in other parts of your application. That would just require more complexity in your d3 javascript code.